# How can I purchase Skype stock during the IPO?

Tags: investing, stocks, brokerage, ipo

Skype will be going IPO soon. How can I purchase their IPO stock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Sign up with a broker that is participating in the IPO. (I don't think that the date is even set yet, so it's probably a little early to check.)
- Read and follow their instructions. [Here's E*Trade's IPO center HowTo](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/ipo/IPOCenter?Message=IPOHowto:1) as a sample.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine you would need a lot of money to enter, and tbh I thought the shares are already allocated, thus ruling out members of the public purchasing any until after the ipo  The IPO is the **public** offering, obviously, and you being a member of the public will have to wait until they are listed ... ?

My answer would be you can't buy stock until after the ipo, until then the company is held privately.

Comment: any explanation for -1? Jut because the process, of purchasing stock before an ipo exists, does not mean the skype founders are selling any of their stock.

Comment: -1 because you're wrong. You *can* sign up to participate in an IPO and purchase the stock at a price which is sometimes significantly cheaper than the price you'd have to pay once it hits the market on its first day of trading. You're buying *during* the IPO; as *part* of the IPO, and you don't have to wait until afterward.