# I am a small retail investor. Can I invest in the Facebook IPO at the IPO price?

Tags: investing, ipo, current-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I purchase Skype stock during the IPO?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/how-can-i-purchase-skype-stock-during-the-ipo)

I've heard that only big institutional investors will be able to purchase Facebook shares at the Facebook IPO price. A small player like me (I've got an account with Charles Schwab) will have to purchase shares later in the day, after the stock "pops," reducing the chance that I'll benefit from the initial surge in the stock price. Is this true?

Is there any way for a regular guy like me to get in on the Facebook IPO?

Comment: Just in case you were feeling left out, you can now buy Facebook stock for *below* the IPO price! Aren't you glad you waited? :)

Answer (score 5):

I have an account with ETrade. Earlier this week I got [an offer to participate in the IPO proper](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/ipo/IPOCenter?Message=IPOHome:1) (at the IPO price). If Charles Schwab doesn't give you the opportunity, that's a shortcoming of them as a brokerage firm; there are definitely ways for retail investors to invest in it, wise investment or no.

(Okay, technically it wasn't an offer to participate, it was a notice that participation was possibly available, various securities-law disclaimers etc withstanding. "This Web site is neither an offer to sell nor a solicitation to buy these securities. The offer is by prospectus only. This Web site contains a preliminary prospectus for each offering." etc etc).

Comment: In the dot-com boom, I put in for many IPOs, and was lucky to get 100 shares. Over time, the gains really added up. I wondered how long the mis-pricing could last, and I got my answer.

Comment: Yeah, you probably shouldn't invest any money in any IPO if you wouldn't be comfortable losing every penny. :)

Comment: I've also learned that with a company like eTrade you need to have a certain amount invested with them to get invited to an IPO.  Perhaps other investment firms do the same thing?